# Do BDD/ATDD stories replace the need for traditional requirements?

Tags: bdd, requirements, specifications, atdd

From what I can tell from online forums and posts, one of the main focuses of BDD/ATDD seems to be on discussion and ensuring that the customer, developers, testers and other relevant parties are involved in the understanding what the system must do.

**Question 1:** Do BDD/ATDD stories replace the need for traditional requirement specifications, such as the those captured using the [Volere Template](http://www.volere.co.uk/template.htm)?

Because the traditional requirement specifications are one of the key inputs for developers and testers, traditional requirement specifications tend to be comprehensive.

**Question 2:** Should BDD/ATDD stories also be comprehensive enough to allow a system to be fully tested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:** Instead of looking at this question as a black-and-white situation, we should better understand how these two requirements capture methods get along with each other. Writing a `story` in the BDD/ATDD methodologies, or in `Scrum` for example, does not imply removing the templates like `volere` off the table. If we take a look at the `volere` requirements specification [here](http://www11.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/Lehre/WS0809/PR-SWE/Material/volere-template.pdf), we can see that most of the information regards to project-related issues, and the shell used for functional requirements is far from being different to a story. They just have different information, not exclusive one.

**Question 2:** Here we have the advantage coming from the methodology itself. BDD comes from `TDD`, we can more or less rely on the test-first oriented process to allow the team to test the system. But, as I mentioned in question 1, making a BDD/ATDD story more comprehensive is not a sin, and wouldn't compromise the general idea of the story. This would also prove useful when interacting with more experienced clients.